# How to write data to csv file using fwrite in R

Tags: r

One of the columns in my dataframe contains semicolon(;) and when I try to download the dataframe to a csv using fwrite, it is splitting that value into different columns.

> Ex: Input : abcd;#6 After downloading it becomes : 1st column : abcd,
>   2nd column: #6

I want both to be in the same column.

Could you please suggest how to write the value within a single column.

I am using below code to read the input file:

```
InpData <- read.table(File01, header=TRUE, sep="~", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                      fill=TRUE, quote="", dec=",", skipNul=TRUE, comment.char="‌​")
```

while for writing:

```
fwrite(InpData, File01, col.names=T, row.names=F, quote = F, sep="~")
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with data and code so that we can run and test the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `read.csv`? And which separator are you using? `sep=","`?

Comment: I am using below code to read the input file InpData <-
 read.table(File01,header=TRUE,sep="~",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,fill=TRUE,quote="",dec=",",skipNul=TRUE,comment.char="") while for writing fwrite(InpData,File01,col.names=T,row.names=F,quote = F,sep="~")

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give us an example, but it is possible you need to use a different separator than ";"

```
fwrite(x, file = "", sep = ",")
```

> sep:    The separator between columns. Default is ",".

If this simple solution does not work, we need the data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I am using below code to read the input file InpData <- read.table(File01,header=TRUE,sep="~",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,fill=TRUE,quote="",dec=",",skipNul=TRUE,comment.char="‌​") while for writing fwrite(InpData,File01,col.names=T,row.names=F,quote = F,sep="~")